# Archive and remove the files from folders using wildcard characters

Tags: c#, .net, wildcard

Let us consider,

```
E:/Folder2/Fol24/Fo2222
E:/Folder3/Fol23/Folder333
E:/Folder4/Folde25/Fold44
E:/Folder5/Folder55/Folde5
```

I need to archive and remove all the files from wildcard character matching folders using some input like `E:/Folder?/Fol2?/Fo*`
Here I am expecting the folders `E:/Folder2/Fol24/Fo2222` and `E:/Folder3/Fol23/Folder333`

The problem here is the user can enter any pattern of wildcard characters. According to the pattern, I have to copy the files to other location and remove the files. Here I can't use any fixed search pattern. It should be dynamic and can have any number of wildcard characters.

Thanks for your help.

Regards
Chandra

Comment: You can restrict the types of wildcards that users can input, and in code-behind, foreach folder or file field, you can 'translate' the wildcards to regular expressions [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to validate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static List<string> folders = new List<string>();

    private void buttonExample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folders.Clear();

        string input = textBox1.Text;
        string currentDir = string.Empty, currentPattern = string.Empty, nextPattern = string.Empty;

        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (c == '?')
            {

                string[] f = input.Split(new[] {'?'}, 2);
                if (f[0].Length > 0)
                {
                    currentDir = Directory.GetParent(f[0]).FullName;
                }

                if (f[1].Length > 0)
                {
                    nextPattern = f[1].TrimStart('\\');
                }

                string[] w = input.Split('\\');
                foreach (string s in w)
                {
                    if (s.Contains('?'))
                    {
                        currentPattern = s;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
            else if(c == '*')
            {
                string[] f = input.Split(new[] { '*' }, 2);

                if (f[0].Length > 0)
                {
                    currentDir = Directory.GetParent(f[0]).FullName;
                }
                if (f[1].Length > 0)
                {
                    nextPattern = f[1].TrimStart('\\');
                }

                string[] w = input.Split('\\');
                foreach (string s in w)
                {
                    if (s.Contains('*'))
                    {
                        currentPattern = s;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
        List<string> foldersNew = new List<string>();
        foldersNew = GetAllFolders(di, currentPattern, nextPattern);
    }

    private static List<string> GetAllFolders(DirectoryInfo currentDir,string currentPattern, string nextPatten)
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] dis = currentDir.GetDirectories(currentPattern);
        if (dis.Length == 0 && string.Equals(currentPattern,string.Empty))
            folders.Add(currentDir.FullName);

        if (dis.Length > 0)
        {
            string[] remainPattern = nextPatten.Split("\\".ToCharArray());
            if (remainPattern.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis)
                {
                    GetAllFolders(di, remainPattern.First(),
                                   string.Join("\\", remainPattern.Skip(1).ToArray()));
                }
            }

        }

        return folders;
    }
```

My solution might be helpful for those who need. This will solve the problem. Thanks for all for your help.

Reference taken from: [Parsing an canonical path with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306445/parsing-an-canonical-path-with-wildcards)